# `Hash#[]` gives TypeError after ordering the hash

Tags: ruby, hash, integer

With the following code:

```
text = "hello dog hello"
words = text.split(" ")
frequencies = Hash.new(0)
words.each { |word| frequencies[word] += 1 }
```

I get:

```
frequencies # => {"hello" => 2, "dog" => 1}
frequencies["test"] # => 0
```

If I add the following two lines after the first code above:

```
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by {|a, b| b }
frequencies.reverse!
```

then do `frequencies["test"]`, I get this error:

```
in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

I guess something's happening to `frequencies`, but I can't understand what. I also tried `puts frequencies["test"].to_s` without any luck. How can I have my program to print `0`? `"test"` does not exist as a key after printing the ordered hash.

Comment: So someone downvoted all answers and the question. Can we get any comments?

Comment: there was a third answer which looked pretty good as well, and now it disappeared ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) returns an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html). `Array`s are indexed by [`Integers`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html), but you index it using a [`String`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) on line 9.

You need to convert the `Array` back to a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html), for example using the [`Array#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_h) method:

```
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
```

Note: this has nothing to do with printing. The error message clearly tells you that the error is on line 9, *after* printing and it tells you that the error is in your call to the `[]` method.

Comment: great, thank you! after few testing I noticed that frequencies[0] gave me values but I didn't get the reason. Now I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because you call `.sort_by` which returns array of arrays. 
Following code converts it back to hash and sets back default value to 0:

```
text = "hello dog hello"
words = text.split(" ")

frequencies = words.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word, o| o[word] += 1 }
frequencies = frequencies.sort_by{ |_, v| v }.reverse.to_h
frequencies.default = 0
p frequencies         #=> {"hello"=>2, "dog"=>1}
p frequencies["test"] #=> 0
```